# How to remove all comments/annotations in multiple pdfs from command line

Tags: command-line, pdf

Are there any open source solution to remove all the comments/annotations from PDF files using command line?

I searched around, and it seems that there are solutions with commercial software, e.g. , by [javascripting Acrobat Pro](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/How-identify-documents-Annotations-remove-annotations-q9354.aspx). The non-free `cpdf` also has [a command line option](http://www.coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual/node61.html):

> The -remove-annotations operation removes all annotations from the
>   given page range.

But I couldn't find such an option for open source tools such as `pdftk`. Any pointers?

Comment: Perhaps you might get some illumination from
https://superuser.com/questions/221711/batch-remove-comments-from-pdf-files